# Are Sub procedures processing RSS posts (which provide a PostItem object as argument) possible as a script destination in Outlook 2013?

Tags: vba, outlook

(Running on Win 8.1)

**The ultimate goal is the answer to this question:**

Using VBA in Outlook 2013, how can I examine incoming RSS posts for contained keywords?

---

**The details so far:**

As per this page: http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/outlooks-rules-and-alerts-run-a-script/ (first paragraph after the initial quote), it is possible to have a VBA script in Outlook 2013 to process `PostItem` arguments.

RSS feeds provide a `PostItem` argument, as in

```
Public Sub ScanRSSPost(Item As Outlook.PostItem)
    ...
End Sub
```

However, the rules wizard won't show this procedure.

Other procedures processing mails coming in and having a `MailItem` argument as in

```
Sub AddMailToOPQueue(oMail As Outlook.MailItem)
    ...
End Sub
```

are displayed as selectable scripts in the wizard and work as expected.

Is the lady simply wrong, or am I overlooking a setting of which I am not aware?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot process incoming RSS items the way `Application.NewMailEx` lets you process new messages, but you can still use `Items.ItemAdd` event on the folder corresponding to a particular RSS feed.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the claim in the quoted post simply does not work.

If you have the same question, here is a work-around:

(1) In Outlook, create a new rule: on receiving any feed (or the particular one you are interested in), forward it to your mail address (I created a dedicated one to keep things clean and uncluttered), and process no further rules.

(2) On the receiving mail address, create a new rule calling a script like this:

```
Sub AddMailToOPQueue(oMail As Outlook.MailItem)
    ...
End Sub
```

In the routine, the forwarded RSS posts' `oMail.Body` property will start with: blank, vbCrLf, blank, vbCrLf, "Feed: ", so to extract the feed in question, you can use something similar as:

```
    If Left(sBody, 12) = " " & vbCrLf & " " & vbCrLf & "Feed: " Then
        sFrom = Mid(sBody, 13)
        sFrom = Left(sFrom, InStr(sFrom, vbCrLf) - 1)

        'sFrom has the feed name now. The post's subject is in oMail.Subject.
        ...
    End If
```

(3) In Outlook, create another rule for the addressee, on receiving items executing above script, which will be selectable in the wizard.